# Gazebo-Garden : [GUI] [Err] [VisualizeLidar.cc:251] Lidar pointer is not set

Tags: sensors, gazebo, lidar, errors

When running `gz-sim/examples/worlds/visualize_lidar.sdf` ([link](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/tree/main/examples/worlds)), I get an error message `[GUI] [Err] [VisualizeLidar.cc:251] Lidar pointer is not set`, what does this mean? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two accounts? Your [suggested edit](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17965) is from a different account  - with a similar name. You can merge the two accounts.

Comment: Can you provide more details as to which version of Gazebo you are using and what platform you're running it on?

Answer (score 2):

I created a pull request to prevent that error msg from being printed.
https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/pull/2077